# node js socket io that is blocked by ufw

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io, firewall

i installed socket.io v 0.9.16 , express v 4.1  in ubuntu 12.04 with 'open VZ' 1gb ram as a very fast alternative for ajax and reduce server load for a my site every thing is good.

but with about 700 clients online and more problem appears
i checked server load is below 0.1
i checked sys log i see some ufw ban messages "[ufw block]" that means :my clients is blocket with firewall

i removed some default ufw because of open vz for ufw works
i added this rule in ufw for dos protection

```
-A INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m state --state NEW -m limit --limit 50/minute --limit-burst 200 -j ACCEPT

-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -m limit --limit 50/second --limit-burst 50 -j ACCEPT
```

disabling ufw reduces my problem but i have some another problems too

xhr and jsonp is acitvated instead of websocket 
and sometimes serving static socket.io files is faied to load for some clients

with about 800 online clients and more

my code is attached

```
var app = require('express')()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

server.listen(8080);

io.enable('browser client minification' , true);
io.enable('browser client etag' , true);
io.enable('browser client gzip' , true);

  io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
  , 'htmlfile'
  , 'xhr-polling'
  , 'jsonp-polling'
  ]);

io.set('log level', 1);
var run = 0;

var md5 = require('MD5');
var hash = md5("my secret");

function sendPrices(data) {
  io.sockets.emit('prices', JSON.parse(data));
}

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  res.end('');
  if(hash == req.query.secret) {
    sendPrices(req.query.prices);
  }
});

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    run++;
    socket.emit('online', run);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(socket) {
        run--;
    });
});


function sendOnlines() {
  io.sockets.emit('online', run);
}

setInterval(function() {sendOnlines();}, 10000);
```

just get 100 byte data every 4 sec from main server and send data to all connected clients
but seems not affected at all (tested)

at the end thanks for help